# How can I get a reference of the sender circle in angular google maps component

Tags: angular, angular-google-maps

When I use circle events in Angular Google Maps component (https://github.com/angular/components/tree/main/src/google-maps), I cannot get a reference to the affected circle instance for retrieving the modified data.

E.g. I have multiple editable and draggable circles on the map.

```
<map-circle *ngFor="let c of ConCircles"
            [center]="c.center"
            [options]="c.options"
            [radius]="c.radius"
            (centerChanged)="CircleCenterChanged($event)"
            (radiusChanged)="CircleRadiusChanged($event)">
</map-circle>
```

The ConCircles element model looks like this:

```
this.ConCircles.push({
            center: {
                lat: startLat,
                lng: startLon,
            } as google.maps.LatLngLiteral,
            options: {
                fillColor: this.api.MapColors[this.ConCircles.length],
                strokeWeight: 1,
                fillOpacity: 0.8,
                editable: true,
                draggable: true,
                clickable: true,
            } as google.maps.CircleOptions,
            radius: (maxDist * 1000) as number
        });
```

I try to use the **radiusChanged** event to retrieve the new radius of the currently edited circle, and I try to use the **centerChanged** event to save the new center coordinate back into the model behind. But since these events have no arguments ($event is undefined), I cannot retrieve the changed values.

Package versions:

```
 "@angular/core": "16.1.1",
 "@angular/google-maps": "16.1.1"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out that using @ViewChildren decorator helps.

Template:
Use a template reference variable, e.g. #circleRef.

Then declare ngFor index (i) and pass it to the event handlers where we need an instance of the MapCircle object.

```
<google-map ...>
    ...
    <map-circle #circleRef
                *ngFor="let c of ConCircles; let i = index"
                [center]="c.center"
    
                [options]="c.options"
                [radius]="c.radius"
                (centerChanged)="CircleCenterChanged($event, c, i)"
                (radiusChanged)="CircleRadiusChanged($event, c, i)">
    </map-circle>
    ...
</google-map>
```

Code behind:
Declare a QueryList property with @ViewChildren decorator for holding all MapCircle instances created on the map.

```
@ViewChildren(MapCircle) map_circles: QueryList<MapCircle>;
```

Event handler functions:
I'm not sure that this is the best way the do the validity check on a QueryList, but it looks reasonable.

Check the map_circles list for dirtiness and if it has any items using the `map_circles.dirty` and `map_circles.first` properties.

If it is not dirty and it has items, then try to get the idxth item of the collection by first converting it to an array, then index into it.

Then do null-guard.

```
    CircleRadiusChanged(args: any, c: ConCircle, idx: number) {
        if (this.map_circles.dirty || this.map_circles.first === undefined) {
            return;
        }
        const modifiedCircle = this.map_circles.toArray()[idx];

        if (!modifiedCircle) {
            return;
        }
        // ...
    }
```